# Is there any way that I can use ember-data way instead select2?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-simple-auth

When I did not use Ember-data, my `select2` component like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    var _this = this;
    this.$().select2({
      placeholder: "waiting...",
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      ajax: {
        url: "/api/fitting_items/select_search",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data(term, page) {
          return {
            q: term,
            stock_type: _this.get('stockType'),
            stock_id: _this.get('stockId')
          }
        },
        results(data, page) {
          return {
            results: data.fitting_items
          }
        },
        cache: true,
      }
    });
  },

  willDestroyElement() {
    this.$().select2('destroy');
  }
})
```

`ember-simple-auth 0.7.3`

But I update my project now, I use

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember             : 2.4.3
DEBUG: Ember Data        : 2.4.3+a3e2521f85
DEBUG: jQuery            : 2.2.2
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 1.0.0
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

And the `ember-data` use `json-api`, so my `select2` component has some problem.

1. If I use `select2` ajax, I must set `token` in the header. Because `Ember Simple Auth : 1.0.0` must set `token` by myself if I set custom ajax requet.
2. I think if I use `select2` `ajax` is not ember data way. It maybe use `this.store.query('fittingItem', params)` will better.
3. If I do not use `select2`, I write a component like `select2` is too difficult for me.

So to sum up, I should use what kind of method to solve this problem is better? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [Ember-power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/)? We are using it along ember-data with JSON-API and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks. @Pavol .  I only find `ember-select-2` and `ember-cli-select2` by google and they not update any more. I think Ember-power-select is very cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ember Legacy Views](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-legacy-views) if you don´t want to update your code atm, but you should update soon

Comment: I think my problem is not with view.